# Creating new dataframe from filtered column of a dataframe

Tags: python

I have the below dataframe:

```
             Genre    NA_Sales  
0            Sports     41.49  
1          Platform     29.08  
2            Racing     15.85  
3            Sports     15.75  
4      Role-Playing     11.27  
...             ...       ...  
16594       Shooter      0.01  
16595        Racing      0.00  
16596        Puzzle      0.00  
16597      Platform      0.01  
16598           NaN       NaN
```

I'm trying to create a new dataframe where each of the Genres are a separate column so that I can then put the data into a boxplot. How would I do that? The expected outcome should look something like:

```
   Platform   Racing    Sports
0   29.08      15.85    41.49
1    0.01      0.00     15.75
```

The expected dataframe should have a single value for each genre listed in the original dataframe (16599 values)

Comment: Can you edit your post by adding the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pivot your data frame from long to wide with the `pivot` method.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot

genres = cycle(['Sports', 'Platform', 'Racing', 'Sports', 'Role-Playing', 'Shooter', 'Racing', 'Puzzle', 'Platform'])

# Initialise sample data

data = {'Genre': [next(genres) for genre in range(0, 1000)],
        'NA_Sales': np.random.randint(0, 50, size = 1000)}

# # Create DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pivot the data frame from long to wide

df = df.pivot(values='NA_Sales', columns='Genre')

# Create the boxplot 

cols = ['Sports', 'Platform', 'Racing', 'Sports', 'Role-Playing', 'Shooter', 'Racing', 'Puzzle', 'Platform']
df.boxplot(column=cols, rot = 90)


plt.show()
```

**Boxplot**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Since you need to visualize using `boxplot`, you first need to aggregate the data frame before displaying the boxplot.
  You can simply make use of `pandas.pivot_table()` method to do the transformation and also display the `boxplot` using the `.boxplot()` method. By default, the aggregation method used in `pandas.pivot_table()` is `'mean'` but you can change that by changing the default value of  `aggfunc` parameter e.g.

```py
example = df.head()
example
```

```
             Genre    NA_Sales  
0            Sports     41.49  
1          Platform     29.08  
2            Racing     15.85  
3            Sports     15.75  
4      Role-Playing     11.27
```

```
agg_data = pd.pivot_table(example, values='NA_Sales', columns='Genre', aggfunc='sum')
agg_data
```

```
Genre     Platform  Racing  Role-Playing  Sports
NA_Sales     29.08   15.85         11.27   17.24
```

And to display the boxplot, you can simply call `.boxplot()` from `agg_data` i.e

```
agg_data.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

- You can make use of the **`seaborn`** library to display the boxplot without aggregating the data (**`seaborn`** can handle it for you easily) e.g.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Genre', y='NA_Sales')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey - The OP won't be able to generate a boxplot from the data if everything is summed up.

Comment: I just used that as an example so that @CLook will be familiar with `aggfunc` parameter. Still yet I think it will work as expected/